# cpf:document-set-state is not working as expected in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am using CPF.

A domain is created for a collection scope (triggers are fired if there is any document created or updated in a particular collection).

I am trying to explicitly set the document state to `xs:anyURI('http://marklogic.com/states/updated')` using `cpf:document-set-state`.

for few URIS triggers are fired and for few not fired (all uris belong to the collection which is used in the domain)

The URIS for which the triggers are not fired, I ran `xdmp:node-replace` (replaced a node with the same text) first.

After running the `xdmp:node-replace` the `cpf:document-set-state` starts working as expected. I could see a trigger is fired.

I am not able to understand why first time no trigger got fired when I set the document state to `xs:anyURI('http://marklogic.com/states/updated')`

Answer (score 2):

CPF operates two interlocking state machines: one that decides whether CPF is interested in doing anything with the document at all (recorded via the cpf:processing-status property) and one for a particular application that records where the document is in that application (recorded via the cpf:state attribute).

Since CPF updates these properties in the course of operating, and since it needs to respond to changes in properties, a lot of the CPF code concerns itself with avoiding creating cascades of triggers responding to its own actions when it shouldn't.

So, if what you want to do is trigger a document to go through its application state machine as if it had just been updated, the simplest way to do that is to update it, i.e. the node-replace and nothing else. If you have the status change pipeline in place, it will take care of the rest. It costs no more or less to update a property fragment as to update a document fragment.

If you want to poke a document to start processing but start in a state other than the one it would normally get to from a document update (i.e some intermediate state in your application pipeline), you need to set the processing status to "active" and the state to the intermediate state. But this is a ninja move, and I'd really suggest you do the simpler thing unless you have a good reason not to.